# How to execute a script 20 at a time with different variables at a time in parallel?

Tags: linux, bash, parallel-processing, pid

I am trying to run 20 `files` at a time, using warc.sh or a better way to put it is 20 instances of warc.sh at a time with directory contents as the input. I am also trying to watch the PIDs in case bad things might happen, and load a new instance with a new input each time an old instance terminates.

```
# test if files exists and run
if [ "$(ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule)" ]; then

    # function to be backgrounded
    track()
    {
      ./warc "${base_dir}/schedule/$1 printf" "\nFinished: %d\n" "$1"
    }

    start=$(date '+%s')

    # Make an associative array in which you'll record pids.
    declare -A pids

    # Background an instance of the track() function for each number, record the pid.
    for n in `ls -A ${base_dir}/schedule`; do
        if [ ${#pids[@]} > 20 ]; then
          track $n &
          pid=$!
          echo "Backgrounded: $n (pid=$pid)"
          pids[$pid]=$n
        else
            echo 'Sleeping' ; sleep 2
        fi
    done

    # Watch your stable of backgrounded processes.
    # If a pid goes away, remove it from the array.
    while [ -n "${pids[*]}" ]; do
      sleep 1
      for pid in "${!pids[@]}"; do
        if ! ps "$pid" >/dev/null; then
          unset pids[$pid]
          echo "unset: $pid"
        fi
      done
      if [ -z "${!pids[*]}" ]; then
        break
      fi
      printf "\rStill waiting for: %s ... " "${pids[*]}"
    done

    printf "\r%-25s \n" "Done."
fi
```

Right now this is completely snowballing out of control and creating plus 900 background process =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write `Makefile` for it and run `make -j 20`.
You can write Makefile with shell script

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what is going on

Comment: You need parallel processing and use some bash script for it, but your script doesn't work.
I suggest don't reinvent already existing and well-working tools.